# How to start Boost echo server in a separate thread

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I was using boost version boost 1_64_0  to run a Tcp server in a seprate thread

This was the code for the server.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

in the Main loop i could spawn a new thread like this.

```
int main()
{

// Run the boost echo server as a different thread
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
server server1(io_service, 1980);   
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &io_service));    

// when about to close the program
io_service.stop(); // stop the server
t.join();
}
```

Now i have changed the boost version to boost_1_73_0 and i am using this example to create a server

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

how do to create a new thread ?

The existing code to create a new thread gives error.

1. io_service: left of :: must be a class/struct/union
2. run : undeclared identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `&io_service::run`, `io_service` is not a type but the local variable by that name.

Starting from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

```
    io_context.run();
```

Needs to be like

```
    std::thread t([&] { io_context.run(); });
    // ...
    t.join();
```

Or if you insist:

```
    std::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io_context));
```

I would use a thread_pool to shortcut all the complexities¹:

```
    boost::asio::thread_pool io(1);

    server s(io.get_executor(), std::atoi(argv[1]));

    // ...
    io.join();
```

A trivial edit to the class interface is required (see e.g. [Boost 1.70 io_service deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776833/boost-1-70-io-service-deprecation/64789000#64789000))

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e700929fb32c5084)**

```
//
// async_tcp_echo_server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2020 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
  public:
    session(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)) {}

    void start() { do_read(); }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                if (!ec) {
                    do_write(length);
                }
            });
    }

    void do_write(std::size_t length) {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
            [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server {
  public:
    template <typename Executor>
    server(Executor ex, short port)
            : acceptor_(ex, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                }

                do_accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::thread_pool io(1);

        server s(io.get_executor(), std::atoi(argv[1]));

        // ...
        io.join();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

¹ see e.g. [Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught/44500924#44500924)

Comment: thank you for the answer , your reply is awesome as usual.

Comment: Does `server(Executor ex, short port)` lead to a copy of `thread_pool io`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis  no (why would it?). An executor is conceptually a reference (to an executor context) but with extra behavior implied. Copying a reference is cheap (both in time and space)

Comment: I wonder what made a person downvote. @MichaelFoukarakis did I misspeak? Perhaps I should have pointed to the documentation to support my explanation. Sadly I cannot find it, but it's in [this presentation](https://think-async.com/executors/Executors_and_Asynchronous_Operations_Slides.pdf) by Chris Kohlhoff e.g. "Like allocators, executors are lightweight and cheap to copy"

Comment: No I haven't downvoted. Thanks for the answer, I was wondering whether a temporary creation & copy might lead to 2x the number of threads in the pool but I guess I need a look into boost source.

Comment: Ugh, not "in the pool", obviously not happening, but in two pools.